# Can an Akka actor participate in an XA transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc, akka, xa

Can an [Akka](http://akka.io/) actor participate in an [XA transaction](http://www.narendranaidu.com/2006/01/what-are-xa-transactions-what-is-xa.html)?  For example, can an actor send a message to a remote actor within the same XA transaction as a database operation (assuming the JDBC driver is an XA driver) such that if the database operation fails, the actor won't send the message?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up with the transaction synchronization in order to send the message when the tx was committed.

But keep in mind the message-send-semantics. There is no ACID guarantee in actor communication. This is not desired at all.

Comment: What happens if the actor fails to send the message? How can the actor rollback a transaction that the database has already committed? Why is an ACID (or at least atomicity and durability) guarantee not desirable for sending actor messages?